# Need to understand VUE Property or method "range" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I need help understanding why the error would show. An example is when I use [vue2-daterange-picker](https://github.com/Innologica/vue2-daterange-picker).

```html
<date-range-picker
  :singleDatePicker="range"
>
</date-range-picker>
```

So `singleDatePicker` is a prop correct? Why is it if I pass the value into the component this way, it returns the error, but if I add the value, `range` into `data` it doesn't? eg

```html
<template>
  <date-range-picker
    :singleDatePicker="singleDatePicker"
  >
  </date-range-picker>
</template>

<script>  
export default {
  components: {
    DateRangePicker
  },
  data () {
    return {
      singleDatePicker: "range",
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `:` (it's the same as `v-bind`) you are binding value, and `range` is not defined, so if you want to put data directly in your prop `singleDatePicker="range"`